# Tkinter: Calling one class method and from another class

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

I have a Tkinter GUI with multiple pages. I am trying to call a method from one page with a button on another page. The method gets called, but I get `AttributeError: type object 'CalibrationPage' has no attribute 'gif_label'`.

If I call this method within its own class I do not get this error and the method works without problem (i.e. putting button within the same class to call method). But I need it to be called prior to displaying the page frame.

I am calling the `update_calibration()` function in the `class CalibrationPage` from the `class LoginPage` using the button `login_btn`.

```
class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # initializes grid to have evenly weighted rows and columns for the page
        cols = 0
        while cols < 20:
            self.grid_columnconfigure(cols, weight=1)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(cols, weight=1)
            cols += 1

        # Button used for temporary navigation between pages
        self.login_btn = ttk.Button(self, text="Login",  command=
                            lambda: [on_return(event='<Return>'),
                                     CalibrationPage.update_calibration(CalibrationPage)])
        self.login_btn.grid(row=19, column=5, rowspan=1, columnspan=7, pady=5, padx=10,
                            sticky='NSEW')
        self.login_btn.bind('<Return>', controller.login_verify)


class CalibrationPage(tk.Frame):

    def update_calibration(self):
        CalibrationPage.gif_label.start_animation()


    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # initializes grid to have evenly weighted rows and columns for the page
        cols = 0
        while cols < 20:
            self.grid_columnconfigure(cols, weight=1)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(cols, weight=1)
            cols += 1

        #       the next page after done.
        self.gif_label = AnimateGIF(self, spinner_file, 0.04)
        self.gif_label.grid(row=9, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=20, padx=10, pady=5,
                            sticky='NSEW')
        # self.gif_label.start_animation()
```

Comment: There is not enough code in your question to answer it. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Note that `update_calibration()` is **not** a class method, it's a regular method and therefore must be call on an _instance_ of  class `CalibrationPage`.